# Compiler generates call to memcpy from std::copy when pointers are of __restrict type?

Tags: c++, gcc, copy, g++, libstdc++

The gcc compiler generates call to `memcpy` when i add `__restrict` to function parameters.
How does compiler/standard library figure out that it can generate calls to `memcpy` when appropriate?

```
void call_stdcpy_r(int *__restrict p, int *__restrict q, int sz) {
  std::copy(p, p+sz, q); // generates call to memcpy
}

void call_stdcpy(int *p, int *q, int sz) {
  std::copy(p, p+sz, q); // generates call to memmove
}
```

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

> The behavior is undefined if the source and the destination ranges overlap.

Shouldn't the compiler, in principle, generate calls to `memcpy` all the time?

Link to godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/aKj3Y5K8M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quote applies to `std::copy_if`, not to `std::copy`.

The only requirement for `std::copy` is that `q` is not in the range `[p,p+sz)`. The destination range is allowed to overlap and therefore `memmove` is the only option without additional assumptions, such as introduced by `__restrict`.

`__restrict` guarantees the compiler that the ranges will not overlap.

Comment: it says both the source and destination *ranges* cannot overlap.

Comment: @A.K. But that applies to `std::copy_if`, not `std::copy`. (?)

Comment: Ah makes sense. I should have read carefully.